# Using a generic model in ASP.NET MVC Razor

Tags: generics, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Is it possible to use a generic model in ASP.NET MVC 3 (w/ Razor)? The following fails with a syntax error:

```
@model DtoViewModel<T> where T : IDto
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Such syntax is not supported by Razor, sorry.

Comment: Bummer. I'd love to see support for it in the future, but I haven't seen anyone else griping about it so I doubt that it'll gain any kind of traction. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I want this!  So that's gripe or at least a request from one other person.

Answer (score 32):

given that @model is expecting a type - not a type declaration
you could use:

```
@model DtoViewModel<IDto>
```

and take advantage of generic covariance

Answer (score 7):

Assuming, you want to use a generic type in order to avoid code duplications in each view of `ViewModel<T>` you can do it this way:

**1.** create a view for the parts of `ViewModel<T>` that are unique to the view

*ModelView.cshtml*:

```
@model ViewModel<specificType>

@{Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Layout.cshtml";}
<h2 class="sub-header">Specific type view</h2>
```

**2.** create a view for the common parts, that should be rendered in each view of `<T>`

*Grid.cshtml*:

```
@{ var webGrid = new WebGrid(Model.PageItems); }

<div class="row" style="overflow: auto">
    @webGrid.GetHtml("table-striped", mode: WebGridPagerModes.All, firstText: "First", lastText: "Last")
</div>
```

Since it's a partial view, you don't need to declare the type of `Model` again. It will simply use the model you defined in the parent view, that renders it. The property `IList<T> PageItems` of your model, will remain strongly typed with `<specificType>`.

**3**. Don't forget to actually render the partial view of your common parts

*ModelView.cshtml*:

```
@RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/Grid.cshtml")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not ideal, but it works and could get pretty creative with this pattern.

```
@model YourNameSpace.MyModel


public MyModel
{
    public MyGenericType<string> ModelAStuff {get;set;}
    public MyGenericType<int> ModelBStuff {get;set;}
    public MyGenericType<DateTime> ModelCStuff {get;set;}
}

public class MyGenericType<T>
{
  //use T how ever you like
  public T Color {get;set;}
  public T Year  {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Since long, I have been working this way. It is not extremely nice, but seems to be the best solution at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I found this thread and did some further digging.  Looks like the **feature is on the 2.2.0 backlog**.  If anyone wants to get involved you can check out the issue on Github.  https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7152

Comment: Too bad. The issue is closed as not planned.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft uses **interfaces** in many of their libraries to overcome this type of restriction. Here is my implementation that allows me to send in any generic **model**. My view is a **partial**.

Note: *because I want the caller to define where the values come from, the model mostly takes lambda accessors.*

**Partial reference from parent view:**

```
<partial name="EntitySelector.partial" model="
    new EntitySelectionModel<Image>
    { 
        DbSet = (new EcoContext()).Images,
        GetDbEntityDisplayName = e => e.DisplayName,
        GetDbEntityId = e => e.Id,
        GetDbEntityImageValue = e => e.Value,
        GetDbEntityName = e => e.Name,
        Multiselect = false     
    }" />
```

**Model with interface:**

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public interface IEntitySelectionModel
    {
        IQueryable DbSet { get; }
        Func<object, string> GetDbEntityDisplayName { get; }
        Func<object, int> GetDbEntityId { get; }
        Func<object, byte[]> GetDbEntityImageValue { get; }
        Func<object, string> GetDbEntityName { get; }
        bool Multiselect { get; }
    }

    public class EntitySelectionModel<TEntity> : IEntitySelectionModel
            where TEntity : class
    {
        public DbSet<TEntity> DbSet { get; set; }
        IQueryable IEntitySelectionModel.DbSet => DbSet;
        public Func<TEntity, string> GetDbEntityDisplayName { get; set; }
        Func<object, string> IEntitySelectionModel.GetDbEntityDisplayName => e => GetDbEntityDisplayName(e as TEntity);
        public Func<TEntity, int> GetDbEntityId { get; set; }
        Func<object, int> IEntitySelectionModel.GetDbEntityId => e => GetDbEntityId(e as TEntity);
        public Func<TEntity, byte[]> GetDbEntityImageValue { get; set; }
        Func<object, byte[]> IEntitySelectionModel.GetDbEntityImageValue => e => GetDbEntityImageValue(e as TEntity);
        public Func<TEntity, string> GetDbEntityName { get; set; }
        Func<object, string> IEntitySelectionModel.GetDbEntityName => e => GetDbEntityName(e as TEntity);
        public bool Multiselect { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Partial view implementation:**

```
@model IEntitySelectionModel

<dialog @(Model.Multiselect ? "multiple" : "") >
    @foreach(var entity in Model.DbSet)
    {
        var name = Model.GetDbEntityName(entity);
        <figure id="@Model.GetDbEntityId(entity)" name="@name">
            <img src="@(await Model.GetDbEntityImageValue(entity).Resize(name, 16, 16))" alt="The Pulpit Rock" />
            <figcaption>@Model.GetDbEntityDisplayName(entity)</figcaption>
        </figure>
    }
</dialog>
```