# How to use generic types in razor page models

Tags: c#, generics, razor-pages

I know [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735903/using-a-generic-model-in-asp-net-mvc-razor) question, but it's very old.

I have a base class for all of my forms. It's called `FormPageModel` and it's a generic base class:

```
public class FormPageModel<ReadEntity, WriteEntity> where ReadEntity : class, IReadEntity, new(), where WriteEntity : class, IWriteEntity, new()
```

Now I want to be able to make my `FormLayout.cshtml` which is the base layout for all of my forms, strongly typed.

I tried `@model FormPageModel<IReadEntity, IWriteEntity>` but it's not compiling.

I there a way that I can use generics as my model in Razor Pages?

Answer (score 2):

You can't create an instance of an interface, so `IReadEntity` doesn't meet the `new()` constraint on the `ReadEntity` generic type parameter, and `IWriteEntity` doesn't match the `new()` constraint on the `WriteEntity` generic type parameter.

Even if you remove the `new()` constraints, your class cannot be covariant, so `FormPageModel<SomeReadEntity, SomeWriteEntity>` cannot be cast to `FormPageModel<IReadEntity, IWriteEntity>`.

If you can't use specific types, then you're going to need to use a non-generic base class for your layout model.

```
public abstract class FormPageModel 
{
    ...
}

public class FormPageModel<ReadEntity, WriteEntity> : FormPageModel
    where ReadEntity : class, IReadEntity, new()
    where WriteEntity : class, IWriteEntity, new()
{
    ...
}
```

```
@model FormPageModel
```